# From a MySQL result update a column automatically

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql query that I use to create a view. Would it be possible that while that query runs, it will update a corresponding field from a table and assign a user?

For example:
My query, will give me this view:

```
   dealID |  removalnotes  | rolloverenabled   | rateplanchanges
   1      |  Yes           | Yes               | NULL
   2      | Null           | Null              | NULL
   3      | Null           | Yes               | NULL
   4      | Null           | Yes               | Yes
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT dealID, removalnotes, rolloverenabled , rateplanchanged
FROM invoice_payment
WHERE removalnotes IS NULL OR removalnotes <> 'Yes' 
OR rolloverenabled IS NULL OR rolloverenabled <> 'Yes' 
OR rateplanchanged IS NULL OR rateplanchanged <> 'Yes'
GROUP BY dealID
```

Can I add a subquery there that will do this automatically? If I can, where exactly do I place or how do I place the subquery?

```
UPDATE invoice_payment SET
user = 'User1'
WHERE dealID = dealID
```

Comment: your sample update query will simply set ALL records to have `user = 'User1'`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I would use a stored procedure in a scenario like this. I can't write the procedure for you, but this might help: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures/

Comment: for this situation just that 1 user for now, i have more users but for this specific query, the result should be assigned to that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
           UPDATE 
              invoice_payment AS ip
            CROSS JOIN (
              SELECT dealID, removalnotes, rolloverenabled , rateplanchanged
            FROM invoice_payment
            WHERE removalnotes IS NULL OR removalnotes <> 'Yes' 
            OR rolloverenabled IS NULL OR rolloverenabled <> 'Yes' 
            OR rateplanchanged IS NULL OR rateplanchanged <> 'Yes'
            GROUP BY dealID

            ) AS sq
            SET 
              ip.user = 'User1' 
            WHERE ip.dealID = dealID
```

Comment: Great, this worked fine just needed to remove that comma after 'User1'

Answer (score 0):

You can add a trigger, perhaps it can be solved using it.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/triggers.html